# Godot: change path for object in animation player

Tags: path, godot

I'm animating a sprite(node) via AnimationPlayer and "naturally" if I place it somewhere else the node isn't found anymore, so I wonder if it's somehow possible to re-path said sprite within AnimationPlayer? I can't find any editable path-entry there or any way to drag and drop – update...

Any help is much appreciated, because it seem like I'd have to completely redo (all) the animation(s) otherwise whenever the tree structure changes - and that can't really be, right? I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: it *is* possible to manually edit the animation nodepath (next to the keyframes). For me actually erasing the first position of that path worked (probably in this my-case scenario only).

What seems obvious enough but still might be worth mentioning is the necessity of confirming with Enter! Yes, really...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something like this

```
[sub_resource type="Animation" id=6]
resource_name = "dyn_focus_item"
length = 0.9
tracks/0/type = "value"
tracks/0/path = NodePath("Camera:translation")
tracks/0/interp = 1
tracks/0/loop_wrap = true
tracks/0/imported = false
tracks/0/enabled = true
tracks/0/keys = {
"times": PoolRealArray( 0, 0.9 ),
"transitions": PoolRealArray( 1, 1 ),
"update": 0,
"values": [ Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ), Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) ]
}
```

```
onready var aplay: AnimationPlayer = $AnimationPlayer
func dyn_animate():
        var anim: Animation = aplay.get_animation("dyn_focus_item")
        anim.track_set_key_value(0, 0, Vector3(camera.translation))
        anim.track_set_key_value(0, 1, Vector3(omnilight.translation + Vector3(1, 0, 0)))
        aplay.play("dyn_focus_item")
```

I misunderstood, the track_set_key_value function works on individual keyrfames, and there must be multiple keyframes for a linear interpolation to work.

Comment: @pferft does this example work for you now?